# Which API to use to find Geofence Breach in the direction from start to end

Tags: java, geofencing, google-directions-api

I have used Google Direction API to calculate the duration and distance from start to end destination. How to find that the device has come closer to the destination without looking at the distance. How to know that the device has breached the geofence in 200 meters radius. How to achieve this without using Android SDK. I just want to calculate the distance and get a beep once the device breaches the geofence.

Comment: Hi, I've answered your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30719757/is-there-any-api-for-calculating-geofence-breach-other-than-android-apis/30761966#30761966

Comment: Just to be clear: you want to calculate the actual travelling (by car, on foot, ...) distance between two points, without using the Android SDK?

Comment: Found that using Google Direction API. Also set a radius of 0.2 to determine geofence break. Solved.